# Is there a way to disable split-keyboard for my app in XCode build settings?

Tags: xcode, split, keyboard

iOS/XCODE. The split keyboard seems to make some actions slower, and even causes crash on older devices with my app. I would like to disable this feature in XCode build settings.  Is it possible?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Xcode. The split keyboard is a feature of iOS on the iPad. A 3rd party app can't disable it.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with Xcode settings. This is a feature of iOS. You app cannot control this. Instead of looking to block the normal behavior of the OS, you should see debug and see why your application is crashing. If you do not have an iPad device, you can split the keyboard in the simulator by long pressing the hide keyboard key, and selecting "Split".

Comment: shame, thats what I feared :/   thanks though.  The game is reliable across all iOS devices.. but... somehow with split kb, iTunes purchases are lagged, and low end devices occasionally crash... maybe split kb takes more memory or something... don't see why it should though.

Comment: ok, it looks like the split kb just works differently than regular kb, with different functions and flags (for some inexplicable reason).  will try to find a workaround for unity... http://www.adevelopingstory.com/blog/2012/05/the-ipad-split-keyboard-and-missing-notifications.html

Comment: ok there are workarounds for native, but haven't found anything for unity yet... :/

Comment: @CthulhuJon perhaps you should describe the problem you have.